# "CWOP" on visa, and extension refused under 221G. Can I travel with this visa to the US?

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals, f1-visas

I recently applied for an F-1 visa extension six months before the expiration of my current visa. However, they refused the extension of my visa under 221g and have also written CWOP on my current visa. My current visa is valid until December and I am scheduled to travel back to the States in two days. Can I travel with the current visa or am I required to obtain a new visa before traveling?

Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the tag. I do not belong to the VWP countries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> My current visa is valid until December

Nope, your visa **became invalid** the moment they put **CWOP** stamp on it. It means **Cancelled without prejudice**.

> **Cancelled Without Prejudice:** 
>   A stamp a U.S. Embassy or Consulate puts on a visa when there is a mistake in the visa or the visa is a duplicate visa (two of the same kind). It does not affect the validity of other visas in the passport. It does not mean that the passport holder will not get another visa.

**[U.S. Visas Glossary](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/glossary.html#C)**

Prejudice or not, the visa stands cancelled. If you also have another valid US visa, that other visa is still good to use, but the one they put the stamp on is no longer valid.

> I am scheduled to travel back to the States in two days

**Please do not travel back to United States** if that was the only visa and you are a visa national, You will not be allowed to board the aircraft and if you are allowed you will certainly be refused entry into the US.

I understand that it is very unfortunate and it is stressful to be suddenly left without a visa 2 days before you are about to go back but it is what it is, any advice telling you to *try your luck* will be a disaster and if you don't cancel your ticket in time you risk losing money as well.

My Advice would be to cancel your flight and follow the instructions provided by the consulate in the refusal letter.

> **What does a visa denial under INA section 221(g) mean?**
>
> A visa denial under section 221(g) of the INA means that the consular
>   officer did not have all of the information required to determine if
>   you are eligible to receive a visa. This means you are not eligible
>   for the visa now, but your case is pending further action for one of
>   the following reasons:
>
> **Your application is incomplete and/or further documentation is
>   required** - Applicants whose application forms or other documentation
>   are incomplete are refused. If further documents are required to
>   complete your case, you will be informed what is needed and how to
>   provide it to the embassy or consulate. You will also be given a
>   letter stating your application has been denied under 221(g) and
>   listing which documents you need to provide.
>
> **Administrative processing** - Further administrative processing of your application is required before a decision can be made regarding your eligibility for a visa.
>   You will be given a letter stating this and next-step instructions
>   after the administrative processing is complete.
>
> **Is there something I can do about a refusal under section 221(g)?**
>
> If your application was denied because documentation or information is
>   missing, you can provide the missing documents or information as soon
>   as possible. After submitting the documentation, your visa application
>   can then be processed to conclusion to determine whether you qualify
>   for a visa. You have one year from the date you were refused a visa to
>   submit the additional information. Otherwise, if you do not provide
>   the required additional information within one year, you must reapply
>   for the visa and pay another application fee.
>
> If your application requires further administrative processing, this
>   takes additional time after your interview. Processing times can vary
>   based on individual circumstances.

Source: [State Department](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-denials.html)

Comment: If the application is in administrative processing, it is not necessary to reapply.

Comment: @Hanky Panky Thank you very much for such a detailed explanation. This is very helpful. I was allowed to appear for an interview and they approved my request.

Comment: @VIDHYASHREE you're most welcome. I'm glad it helped and you got your visa sorted :)